# PHP replaced file extension won't load

Tags: php, apache

I have this really old project that needs to be started. It has a bunch of .php files masked as .ap files. When I rename them to .php app starts fine, but with .ap it just opens the code instead of running it.

My .htaacess file has only this code:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .ap
```

Also tried with adding this:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .ap .php
```

Looked online but nothing works. If anyone can help that would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution for this if anyone needs it in the feature. In apache2.conf, allow override for the site that you are using:

```
<Directory /var/www/website>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```